# JSON data displaying without rhyme or reason

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

If this is an issue with me not defining settings properly I thought it might be of interest to other RoR beginners.

I am building a Ruby on Rails 4.0.0 application and have run into a very annoying problem of JSON data displaying for what I can understand as no reason. The error is showing when I am displaying a list of all workshops in a postgres database.
The HTML that is getting displayed:

```
    <h1>Available Workshops</h1>


[#&lt;Workshop id: 1, name: "lolll", workshoptype: "workshop1", location: "3923 west 11th", created_at: "2015-01-27 02:18:00", updated_at: "2015-01-27 02:18:00", cost: nil, starttime: nil, user_id: nil&gt;, #&lt;Workshop id: 2, name: "lolll", workshoptype: "workshop1", location: "3923 west 11th", created_at: "2015-01-27 02:18:28", updated_at: "2015-01-27 02:18:28", cost: nil, starttime: nil, user_id: nil&gt;, #&lt;Workshop id: 3, name: "again", workshoptype: "workshop2", location: "AGAIN", created_at: "2015-01-27 02:19:05", updated_at: "2015-01-27 02:19:05", cost: nil, starttime: nil, user_id: nil&gt;, #&lt;Workshop id: 4, name: "dashit", workshoptype: "workshop3", location: "TROLOL", created_at: "2015-01-27 02:21:03", updated_at: "2015-01-27 02:21:03", cost: nil, starttime: nil, user_id: nil&gt;, #&lt;Workshop id: 5, name: "Tir Workshop", workshoptype: "TIR", location: "White Rock", created_at: "2015-01-27 03:22:26", updated_at: "2015-01-27 03:22:26", cost: 800, starttime: "26/04/1991", user_id: nil&gt;]
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

The table is intentional and the rest of it displays as expected.Also, the rest of the page is formatting correctly.
Here is my view/workshop/index.html.erb file:

```
<h1>Availalbe Workshops</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <%= @workshops.each do |workshop|%>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= workshop.id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to workshop.name, workshop_path(workshop.id) %></td>
      <td><%= workshop.location %></td>
      <td><%= workshop.workshoptype %></td>
      <td><%= workshop.created_at %></td>
      <td>$700</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

And My non admin workshop controller:

```
class WorkshopsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @workshops = Workshop.all
    # respond_to do |format|
    # format.html { render html: @workshops }
    # end
  end

  def show
    @workshop = Workshop.find(params[:id])  
  end

end
```

I wasn't really sure what the respond_to does or its purpose I just thought maybe I could force it to behave accordingly (it made no difference). Is there something obvious that I'm missing like a postgres/controller setting I don't know that is causing this json to echo? 
I am getting an assets error but I'm not sure it's related :

```
Started GET "/workshops" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800
Processing by WorkshopsController#index as HTML
  Workshop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "workshops".* FROM "workshops"
  Rendered workshops/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 10.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/admin/workshops.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/home.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/admin/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/navbar.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/sessions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/workshops.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800


Started GET "/js/bootstrap.min.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 16:36:57 -0800
  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/js/bootstrap.min.js"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/datis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/datis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/datis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/datis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/datis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/datis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/datis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (66.4ms)
```

My log files are clean and I haven't touched my configs except to put in postgres.

At request here is my layout/application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>UnderstandingU</title>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.1/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.1/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

There were some fishy js things going on so I cleaned them up. The js load error has stopped but the JSON is still displaying. 
Here is my layouts/navbar as well:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "navbar" %>

<nav class= "navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      </button>
      <%= link_to "UnderstandingU", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
<!--       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">UnderstandingU</a>
 -->    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to "About Mindy", controller: "home", action: "about" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Workshops", workshops_path, action: "index" %></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Courses <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Traumatic Incident Reduction", controller: "home", action: "tir" %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Life Stress Reduction", controller: "home", action: "lsr" %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to "TIR- Extended Applications", controller: "home", action: "ea" %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", controller: "home", action: "contact"%>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% if current_user %>
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"> Signed in as <%= current_user.firstname %> </p>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li>
       <%= link_to "Log out", session_path(current_user), method: :delete %>
       </li>

      </ul>
      <% else %>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Signup/login", new_user_path %></li>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I know I"m using an old syntax for the home controller but I was having some difficulties getting the action_controller_path behaving as its suppose to.

Comment: Do you have both a 'workshop' as well as a 'workshops' directory?  Is 'Availa**bl**e Workshops' vs 'Availa**lb**e Workshops' just a typo/autocorrect?  Assuming those are just typos, I'm suspicious of your layouts/application, and whatever whatever JavaScript it is including.  It might be worth including layouts/application with your question.

Comment: I updated my layouts/application and _navbar . There was some improperly copied bootstrap CDN so the JS error has stopped but the JSON is still displaying. -edited because apparently I can't type this week.-

Comment: There is only a workshops directory and a workshops controller. Part of the workshops controller is namespaced into an admin dashboard however with its own directory and it's own workshops controller, the only public display is index and show.

Comment: tbody for each workshop is wrong, one tbody encompassing multiple workshops (tr's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= @workshops.each do |workshop|%>`
```

change that to

```
<% @workshops.each do |workshop|%>`
```

Because `<%=` will output the result of the `each` block. This is in your view.

Comment: I'm not sure how long I looked at it already but I clearly never would have seen it. Thanks that was the problem.